# How to return a message to user that the email they input has been registered and redirect to register page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, backend

(solved)

I am writing a register page. There is a problem I face right now. I have two HTML pages `index.html` and `register.html`. When the users submit their informations in `register.html`, I want my code to first to check if their input email has already exists in the database. My register function as following:

```
   app.post('/user_register', (req, res) => {
      const name = req.body.input_name;
      const email = req.body.input_email;
      const phoneNumber = req.body.input_phonenumber;
      const password = req.body.input_password;
      const confirmpassword = req.body.input_confirmpassword;
      const postQuery = 'INSERT INTO registerinfo VALUE (?,?,?,?)';
      const checkQuery = 'SELECT email FROM registerinfo WHERE email = ?';
    
      mysqlConnect.connection.query(checkQuery, [email], async (err, result, fields) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            if (result.length > 0) {
                return app.get('/result', (req, res)=>{
                    res.json(result);
                    res.redirect('/register')
                })
            
                
            } else {
                let hashedPassword = await bcryptjs.hash(password, 8);
                mysqlConnect.connection.query(postQuery, [name, email, phoneNumber, hashedPassword], (err, result, fields) => {
                    if (!err) {
                        console.log('Register SUCCESSFUL!!')
                    } else {
                        console.log(`the error is ${err}`)
                        res.send(500);
                        throw err;
                    }
                })
            } 
    })// query end here
```

The problem start from `if (result.length > 0){}`, my thought is if `result.lenght > 0` as email exists already in database, then use `return app.get()` to send json data to route `/result` and redirect back to `register.html`, `register.html` will always fetch data from route `/result`, if data is not empty, then span a message to users that this email has already been registered.

First of all, redirect back to `register.html` is not working, I tried `res.redirect('/register')` and `res.sendFile(__dirname + './public/register.html')` inside `return`, but once I click submit, it will always get back to `index.html`.

Second, is my thought the right way to achieve what I want? When I look at it, this `return app.get()` inside `app.post()` doesn't look like the right way to do it. And I did find a solution online using handlebars, where it solve this simply with `return res.render('register', {message: 'email is registered '})`, since I didn't use hbs, I try to solve this without it. So if my thought to solve this is wrong to begin with, what is the right way to do it?

Comment: `app.get` and `app.post` are used to register handlers for routes. They do not redirect you anywhere and trying to use them will not work. You have to use `res.redirect`. If you are facing issues with redirect, please edit your question and show the code where you are trying to use redirect.

Comment: I just edited it, it is inside `app.get()`

Comment: Can you clarify, why are you trying to send json data to `/result`? What will that accomplish? Also, I suspect you are using default form submission on front-end, is this correct?

Comment: yes, i'm using bootstrap 5 default form. My purpose is to send a message to the user if the email is already registered. so `register.html` will fetch json data, if data is not empty, then span a message to users. that's why I need it to redirect to `register.html`.  I'm not even sure this is the right way to handle it

Comment: I just solved this, found out the problem. Thanks